# How can I use English language instead of French with the package 'lubridate'?

Tags: r, lubridate

So, I have a project on R and I have to create a variable 'month' and 'day', so I decided to use 'lubridate' package. But the displayed days and months are in French, but I want to have it in English.

I hope that somebody can answer me.
Thank you in advance.

I have just used these two lines of code, they are good, except the language...

`crime19clean$Day <- wday(crime19clean$Newdate, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE) crime19clean$Month <- month(crime19clean$Newdate, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use locale:

```r
lubridate::wday(Sys.Date(), label=T, locale="EN-us")
#> [1] Sat
#> Levels: Sun < Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat
lubridate::wday(Sys.Date(), label=T, locale="FR-fr")
#> [1] sam\\.
#> Levels: dim\\. < lun\\. < mar\\. < mer\\. < jeu\\. < ven\\. < sam\\.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you. for your answer, but when I try to do it, I have a warning message : 



Error in Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale) : 
  (converted from warning) OS reports request to set locale to "En-us" cannot be honored

Comment: Seems to be related to your OS installation. If you can't install a locale in your operative system, try with this workaround: `ordered(lubridate::wday(Sys.Date(), label=F, week_start = 7), levels = 1:7, labels = c("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"))`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, if you have the same problem I just have used :

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US")
```